# MySQL distinction between e and é (e acute) - UNIQUE index

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, indexing, constraints

I have a table, `students`, with 3 columns: `id`, `name`, and `age`. 
I have a `UNIQUE` index `Index_2` on columns `name` and `age`.

```
CREATE TABLE `bedrock`.`students` (  
    `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    AUTO_INCREMENT,   `name` VARCHAR(45)
    NOT NULL,   `age` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT
    NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),   UNIQUE
    INDEX `Index_2` USING BTREE(`name`,
    `age`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I tried this insert option:

```
insert into students (id, name, age)
values (1, 'Ane', 23);
```

which works ok. Than I've tried this one (see **Ané** - **e acute**):

```
insert into students (id, name, age)
values (2, 'Ané', 23);
```

and I receive this error message:

```
"Duplicate entry 'Ané-23' for key 'Index_2'"
```

MySQL somehow does not make any distinction between "Ane" and "Ané".  How I can resolve this and why this is happening?

Charset for table students is "utf8" and collation is "utf8_general_ci".

```
ALTER TABLE `students` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

**Later edit1:  @Crozin:**

I've changed to use collation utf8_bin:

```
ALTER TABLE `students`
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

but I receive the same error.

But if I create the table from start with charset utf8 and collation utf8_bin, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `students2` ( 
`id` INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`name` VARCHAR(45),   `age`
VARCHAR(45),   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
UNIQUE INDEX `Index_2` USING
BTREE(`name`, `age`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

both below insert commands works ok:

```
insert into students2 (id, name, age)
values (1, 'Ane', 23); // works ok

insert into students2 (id, name, age)
values (2, 'Ané', 23); // works ok
```

This seems to be very weird.

**Later edit 2:**

I saw another answer here. I'm not sure if the user deleted or it get lost.
I was just testing it:

The user wrote that first he created 3 tables with 3 different charsets:

```
CREATE TABLE `utf8_bin` (   `id`
int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
AUTO_INCREMENT,   `name` varchar(45)
COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,   `age`
int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,   PRIMARY
KEY (`id`),   UNIQUE KEY `Index_2`
(`name`,`age`) USING BTREE )
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `utf8_unicode_ci` (  
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
AUTO_INCREMENT,   `name` varchar(45)
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,  
`age` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),   UNIQUE KEY
`Index_2` (`name`,`age`) USING BTREE )
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `utf8_general_ci` (  
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
AUTO_INCREMENT,   `name` varchar(45)
COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,  
`age` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),   UNIQUE KEY
`Index_2` (`name`,`age`) USING BTREE )
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

The results of the user are:

```
Insert commands: INSERT INTO utf8_bin
VALUES (1, 'Ane', 23), (2, 'Ané', 23);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

INSERT INTO utf8_unicode_ci VALUES (1,
'Ane', 23), (2, 'Ané', 23); Query OK,
2 rows affected (0.01 sec) Records: 2 
Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

INSERT INTO utf8_general_ci VALUES (1,
'Ane', 23), (2, 'Ané', 23); Query OK,
2 rows affected (0.01 sec) Records: 2 
Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Here are my results:

```
INSERT INTO utf8_bin VALUES (1, 'Ane',
23), (2, 'Ané', 23);        //works ok
INSERT INTO utf8_unicode_ci VALUES (1,
'Ane', 23), (2, 'Ané', 23); //
Duplicate entry 'Ané-23' for key
'Index_2'

INSERT INTO utf8_general_ci VALUES (1,
'Ane', 23), (2, 'Ané', 23);
//Duplicate entry 'Ané-23' for key
'Index_2'
```

I'm not sure why in his part this `INSERT` command worked and for me doesn't work.

He also wrote that he tested this on Mysql on Linux - has to do something with this?!  Even I do not think so.

Comment: Not related to your question, but it's never a good idea to have a unique key on a name field... Many people have the same name. What do you plan to do in that instance? That said, the fact you have created a unique key based on name and age would suggest a design decision.....

Comment: Hi Brendan, this is just an example, a fictive one - is not the same as I have in the project I work! I know is not ok to have an unique index on columns like 'name' and 'age'. I've choose this example (not a very intelligent one - I admin) instead choosing the real example which contains more then 10 columns....

Comment: Answer from the future! utfmb4_german2_ci, utfmb4_swedish_ci, utfmb4_spanish_ci etc. now ship with MySQL/MariaDB, and one of those should fit similar needs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> and collation is "utf8_general_ci".

And that's the answer. If you're using `utf8_general_ci` (actually it applies to all `utf_..._[ci|cs]`) collation then diacritics are bypassed in comarison, thus:

```
SELECT "e" = "é" AND "O" = "Ó" AND "ä" = "a"
```

Results in `1`. Indexes also use collation.

If you want to distinguish between `ą` and `a` then use `utf8_bin` collation (keep in mind that it also distinguish between uppercase and lowercase characters).

---

By the way name and age don't guarantee any uniqueness.

Comment: I've aswered to your answer by updating the question - did not had enough space here.  I've also added "Later edit 2" part.

Comment: related to "name and age don't guarantee any uniqueness" please see my second comment for this question - as a response to Brendan.

Comment: using collation `utf_8 bin` works fine - the only issue that I have is that is case-sensitive and I wanted to be case-insensitive - do you know a solution for this ? Thanks.

Comment: @Paul: I'm afraid that there is no binary-like, case-insensitive collation. I guess you'll have to use two columns. First one for storing actual data and a second for string lowercased text with `utf8_bin` collation and unique index. It means that one column will store `Ané` and second one `ané`. All searches and comparisons should be performed then on the second column.

Comment: Coming from the future! Collations like utfmb4_german2_ci, utfmb4_swedish_ci are now built in and solve this issue (for anyone still reading at this time)

Answer (score 6):

I found that

```
ALTER TABLE students CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

did not work for me, as it didn't change the collation of existing columns, as can be seen in the results of this query:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS from students;
```

However, the following query did the job and converted existing columns to utf8_bin collation:

```
ALTER TABLE students CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

(notice the "CONVERT TO")

Answer (score 2):

Change collation to `latin1_german2_ci`

checkout [collation effects](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-effect.html)

Comment: @Shakti Singh: Using latin-based collation on Unicode-encoded might solve a problem in this particular case but it leads to dozens of new issues.

Comment: For Charset utf8 I do not even have collation latin1_german2_ci.

Comment: @Paul: Charset will become `latin1` with the collation `latin1_german2_ci`

Comment: I've updated the charset and collation as you suggested:

`ALTER TABLE students CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;`

but this did **not** solved the problem.

Comment: @Paul: Did you gone through the example given in the posted link that should work?

Comment: @Shakti Singh: I just tested with charset `latin1` and collation `latin_german2_ci' in my case and it doesn't work and I suposse because `é` is not a german character - is a latin one.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is somewhat old now, but what I had to do was remove the primary key on my table and use a regular index, instead. It seems that MySQL doesn't honor utf8_bin's collation in primary keys. I'm using MySQL 5.5.