# Unique constraint violation with utf-8 values

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I've created the following table in my MySQL (5.6.20) db:

```
CREATE TABLE `Description` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sign_ref` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uq_sign_ref` (`sign_ref`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

When inserting the value `|SU&SU|` into a new `sign_ref` row, I get a constraint violation, because `|ŠU&ŠU|` already exists. This happens whether I do it via SQLAlchemy, or directly using Sequel Pro.

All charset and collation settings are utf8mb4 / utf8 / utf8_general_ci / utf8_unicode_ci, so I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQl distinction between e and é (e acute) - index UNIQUE problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466901/mysql-distinction-between-e-and-%c3%a9-e-acute-index-unique-problem) (in short: `ALTER TABLE Description MODIFY COLUMN  sign_ref varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL`, but that DOES mean you won't find `ŠU&ŠU` when searching for `SU&SU` and you lose case insensitivity, it's either one or the other).