# Mysql UNIQUE KEY constraint - a and å are treated as the same characters

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8, utf8mb4

I have a unique key on a column. When I insert `a` and then `å` it throws an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'å' for key 'constraint-1'' in ..

....But `a` and `å` are different UTF characters - so what's going on....?

table has `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4`  and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation.

Comment: MySQL applies a collation to each column which defines sort order and letter equivalence. For the collation applied to this column those two letters are considered equivalent.

Comment: @HoboSapiens I thought collation is only used for sorting, and the only thing that matters for insertion is a charset??

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQl distinction between e and é (e acute) - index UNIQUE problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466901/mysql-distinction-between-e-and-%c3%a9-e-acute-index-unique-problem)

Comment: That's where you're wrong. See the question I linked to. You need to use the `utf8_bin` collation to distinguish these characters. You can override the default collation with the COLLATE clause. The MySQL reference on the subject is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collations.html)

Answer (score -4):

use collation **`latin1_swedish_ci`** on the unique column.

[image: This is my server screen]

[image: Screen after selecting database]

[image: Screen after selecting table]

[image: Records in the table]

[image: Error while entering duplicate value]

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted you, but I do store utf data - so I think simply  changing collation doesnt work for this case.

Comment: Yes i have tested in same environment and it worked for me.

Comment: my `Server connection collation = utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.  Collation - table `latin1_swedish_ci`.   `latin1_swedish_ci` works perfect for me. Can you please try once.

Comment: here is full detail.
Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.6.24 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: Switching to a more restrictive collation like `latin1_swedish_ci` is daft when the rest of the world is moving to UTF8. Even if this works, it's a poor solution.