# finding non-english numbers starting with ٠٩ returns rows starting with 09

Tags: mysql

We have a column in database called `mobile(varchar 30 - utf8_persian_ci)` which contains some cellphone numbers

Some of them are not in english , im trying to find and edit them

They all start with `٠٩` which is equal to `09`

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE mobile LIKE "%٠٩%"
```

but this query returns all numbers including english ones that start with `09` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use utf8_bin instead of utf8_persian_ci to avoid equivalence issues (٠٩ is equivalent to 09)

See:
[MySQL distinction between e and é (e acute) - UNIQUE index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466901/mysql-distinction-between-e-and-%C3%A9-e-acute-index-unique-problem)

Answer (score 1):

This is because, your database does not recognize non-English characters. Try using `utf_general_ci` Collation. That might solve your problem. You can use the following to change database collation:

```
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf_general_ci;
```

and this to change table collation:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf_general_ci;
```

**EDIT**
: I checked using `utf_general_ci`. Works perfectly for me.

Comment: thanx i will try this and i think it has something to do with char set ... but if database doesn't recognize non-english numbers the query should'nt return any result .. i think somehow it translate numbers to english