# mysql character set utf 8 collation (dup key) not working properly

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, collation

My database tables character-set and collation set to `utf-8` and `utf8_general_ci` respectively. I inserted a record with value `'säî kîråñ'` in varchar column. I have a unique column constraint on that. When I try to insert 'sai kiran' its giving duplicate entry referring to old inserted row of 'säî kîråñ'.

As you can see the characters in both the strings are completely different in utf8 character-set, couldn't understand why it is showing error as 'duplicate entry'.

I tried changing collation to `utf8_unicode_ci` but no use. I tried directly inserting in phpmyadmin to avoid prog lang encoding problems, still the problem persists.

Comment: Are you doing `SET NAMES utf8` after establishing the connection?

Comment: I have large number of inserts so using file upload (with insert statements) in phpmyadmin and ofcouse the default character set selected in phpmyadmin while uploading file was 'utf8'.

Comment: I'm unsure what influence the collation has on the unique constraint, but if it does influence it, you'll want a *bin* collation instead of the general or unicode collations.

Comment: Yah I know utf8_bin works for case-sensitive comparisons. In case of utf8_general_ci I thought only 'a' and 'A' would be treated same, but from [here](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10344217-Difference-between-utf8_general_ci-and-utf8_bin&s=087b5f7ace1f55fb6a25330ca718371f&p=10820221#post10820221) I found that even 'a' and 'ä' would be treated same. So utf8_bin is the ultimate solution to treat them different. Good learning though....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL distinction between e and é (e acute) - UNIQUE index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466901/mysql-distinction-between-e-and-%c3%a9-e-acute-unique-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `utf8_general_ci` I thought only `'a' and 'A'` would be treated same, but from [here](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10344217-Difference-between-utf8_general_ci-and-utf8_bin&p=10820221#post10820221) I found that even `'a' and 'ä'` would be treated same. So `utf8_bin` is the ultimate solution to treat them different. Good learning though.

Comment: Note that `select 'a' = 'ä'` is true, but `select 'a' collate utf8_bin = 'ä' collate utf8_bin` is false.

Comment: In most (not  all) utf8 collations, A=a=À=Á=Á=Â=Ã=Ä=Å=à=á=á=â=ã=ä=å=Ā=ā=Ą=ą .  For utf8_bin, all of those are different.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the lack of a `utf8_..._ci_as`, collation, you should probably change the collation of (at least) that column to be `utf8_bin`.  Then, instead of all of these being equal `S=s=Ş=ş=Š=Š=š=š`, they will all be different.  Note, especially. that `s` and `S` will be distinct in utf8_bin.